# Where is _pthread_get(set)specific_direct defined and implemented in armv7?

Tags: ios, exception, arm

I saw them in libc-8XX/pthreads on opensource.apple.com, but since libc-9xx the pthreads folder are gone, so did these two functions. I saw these two functions were used in _Unwind_SjLj_Register in exception handling on 32-bit IOS platform, but where are they now? or am I just misunderstanding something about them?